# getting 'str' object has no attribute 'get' when using django template tags

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

template

```
 {{ show_details.message|get_value:"data_errors"}}

show_details is a model and
my message is {"other_errors":[{"error":"Column \"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'customer_code'\" not found."},{"error":"Column \"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'employee_number'\" not found."}],"data_errors":{"2":"customer_code 99491 does not exists","order_number":"20","3":"employee_number 57 does not exists"}}

from this dictinoary i neet to get only data_errors values
```

template_tags.py

```py
@register.filter

def get_value(dictionary, key):
   
    print("DICTIONARY",dictionary,"KEYYY",key) 
    #output for this is ('DICTIONARY','','KEYYY',u'data_errors')

    
    return dictionary.get('key')
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: It shows that `dictionary` is a string. It is not a dictionary object as you probably expect. What exactly is your question?

Comment: As you can see, `dictionary` is an empty stiring (`''`), meaning that `show_details.message` is an empty string.

Comment: What is the value of `show_details`?